# не работает distinc

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пишу запрос, без distinct выводит с повторениями, при добавлении distinct ничего не меняется, только отсортировывается

```
SELECT DISTINCT("QP"."MRN") AS MRN ,
CONCAT( "QP"."SecondName", ' ', "QP"."Name", ' ', "QP"."MiddleName") AS fullName,
"App"."Time",
"App"."AppId",
"App"."PId",
"Q"."StartDate"
FROM "App"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "QP"
ON "App"."PId" = "QP"."PId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "DS"
ON "App"."DSId" = "DS"."DSId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Queues"
ON "DS"."QId" = "Q"."QId"
WHERE "App"."PId" notnull
```

в чем проблема?

Comment: так mysql или postgresql  или oracle?)

Comment: а что должно меняться? каков ваш пример данных? а то по стилю написания кажется что вы первую строку рассматриваете как две инструкции `select` и `distinct(x) as x`, а не `select distinct` применяемый ко всей выборке и `(x) as x` который эквивалентен простому `x`

Comment: А в чем по вашему должен состоять вывод с таким distinct ? он какие значения должен показать в остальных полях кроме MRN после того как запись с конкретным MRN останется только одна ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исключить по наличию предиката `notnull` в синтаксисе )

Comment: Это не диалект Oracle, метку удалил.

Comment: Поправил свой некорректный вопрос, проблема в том что не должно быть повторяющихся id

Comment: @Miha, выводит именно с повторениями, или в каком-нибудь из столбцов есть отличия, например в `StartDate`?

Answer (score 1):

По тому как вы расставили скобки, очень похоже, что вы просто не понимаете как работает `DISTINCT`

В записи `SELECT DISTINCT("QP"."MRN")…`

`DISTINCT` - это модификатор команды `SELECT`

`("QP"."MRN")` - выражение для вычисления первого столбца.

`DISTINCT` не имеет параметров, он удаляет одинаковые строки

Answer (score 0):

Может быть Вам надо только одна строка для каждого `"QP"."MRN" AS MRN`? Тогда Вам нужен `DISTINCT ON`. ([детали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by))

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("QP"."MRN")
  "QP"."MRN" AS MRN ,
  CONCAT("QP"."SecondName", ' ', "QP"."Name", ' ', "QP"."MiddleName") AS fullName,
  "App"."Time",
-- и так далее
```

Для неповторяющихся *комбинации* `AppId` и `PId`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("App"."AppId", "App"."PId")
  "QP"."MRN" AS MRN ,
  CONCAT("QP"."SecondName", ' ', "QP"."Name", ' ', "QP"."MiddleName") AS fullName,
  "App"."Time",
-- и так далее
```